# how to remove "www" from a host name in the || context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a variable that i want to set with an empty string "" or with an url if exist but without "www"

```
url =  page.host.sub!(/www./, '') || ""
```

but here if page.host contains a host name already without "www" the `sub!` method will return nil

i want to do something like this

```
url =  page.host.sub!(/www./, '') if page.host.include? "www." || ""
```

but this is not possible to add if statement in this context

how i can solve this ? if there is another (best) way to remove "www" from host i will be thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the ! after sub.

`url =  page.host.sub(/www./, '') || ""`

You would only use sub! if you want to modify page.host.

Answer (score 2):

Just Remove the ! Mark from sub!